# Only chapter names in headers for frontmatter

Tags: header-footer, chapters, fancyhdr

I am desperately trying to find a way to only display the chapter name entirely in upper case on the headers using `fancyhdr` package for the front matter of the `book` class. But I also want to display chapter number and name in the main matter part like usual. I don't like that ugly chapter 0 showing up on the header in the front matter. What shall I do? Below is an MWE for the problem. I used `\if...\fi` here for allowing only the headers to show up in main matter.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\ifnum \value{chapter}>0 \leftmark \fi}
\fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyfoot{}
\lfoot{SAMPLE}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.5pt}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapter{PREFACE}
\lipsum[1-3]
\mainmatter
\chapter{CHAP 1}
\lipsum[4-6]
\chapter{CHAP 2}
\lipsum[7-9]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should redefine the `\chaptermark`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\makeatletter
\def\chaptermark#1{%
          \markboth{\MakeUppercase{%
            \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne \if@mainmatter
              \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ \fi\fi#1}}{}}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyfoot{}
\lfoot{SAMPLE}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.5pt}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\chapter{PREFACE}
\lipsum[1-3]
\mainmatter
\chapter{CHAP 1}
\lipsum[4-7]
\chapter{CHAP 2}
\lipsum[8-10]

\end{document}
```